# UICollectionView Enable deselecting cells while allowsMultipleSelection is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

I can deselect cells that were selected.

when

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

I cannot deselect cells that were selected.

Is there anyway I can only set

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

and

be able to deselect the selected cell? so there would either be one selected or none selected.

I understand you can implement your own selection with a tap gesture then calling setSelected when gesture is detected. But I am looking for a more native solution, something that you could configure on uicollectionView itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to allow multiple selection and clear the previous selection in `didSelect...`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a native solution. This is how I ended up doing it, a bit hacky but it does what's needed. I have `self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES` set in `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath in [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]) {
        [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO];
    }
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The additional selection and deselection in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` is to animate the deselection - an additional benefit this approach provides, being able to animate the transitions.