# UICollectionView CustomCell- Not able to deselect already Selected Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I m using `collectionCell` to select and deselect image on `collectionCell`. **But when i click on selected cell , it wont get deselected**.

I changed my Code as per as Nirav Suggestion and it working for current View but when i m coming from another view by passing some object then those object should be marked checked. If i click on mark objects that is selected it does not deselect the cell.

My Code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

BICollectionCell *cell = (BICollectionCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BICollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

CustVehiclesList *objCustVehiclesList =self.array_VehicleServicesList[indexPath.row];
[cell.labelMake setText:objCustVehiclesList.make];
[cell.lblLicense setText:objCustVehiclesList.licencePlateNo];

if (objCustVehiclesList.vehiclePicture == nil ||[objCustVehiclesList.vehiclePicture isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [cell.imageCarsView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
}
else
{
    NSString *baseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objCustVehiclesList.vehiclePicture];
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:baseString options:0];
    UIImage *imageToDisplay = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [cell.imageCarsView setImage:imageToDisplay];
}

[cell setSelected:YES];
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];

if (self.selectedIndexPath == indexPath)
{
    [cell.imgSelectedImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vs_tick.png"]];
}
else
{
    [cell.imgSelectedImage setImage:nil];
}

if ([objCustVehiclesList.modelName isEqualToString:self.str_ModelName] && _isCalledFromDetailVC)
{
    [cell.imgSelectedImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vs_tick.png"]];
}


if (indexPath.row == self.indexPathToBeSearch.row && self.isCalledFromVehicleVC)
{
    [cell.imgSelectedImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vs_tick.png"]];
}


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does `BICollectionCell` overrides `setSelected:` or `setSelected:animated:`. If yes, do you call `[super setSelected:selected]` or `[super setSelected:selected animated:animated]` in it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330844/uicollectionview-select-and-deselect-issue

Comment: @Larme i am not overriding any thing in bicollection cell then also same exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView Enable deselecting cells while allowsMultipleSelection is disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423778/uicollectionview-enable-deselecting-cells-while-allowsmultipleselection-is-disab)

Comment: Add whole code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Nirav please check

Comment: @Nirav same issue exists bro i have placed ur code and checked then also

Comment: @Imran `self.isCalledFromVehicleVC` is what type of variable? Is it boolean or something else?

Comment: @Nirav self.isCalledFromVehicleVC is a BOOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change image on selection of cell and if cell is already selected and you want to `deselect` it, then you can change your code like this

First Create one instance property `selectedIndexPath` like this

```
@property NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

After that change your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BICollectionCell *cell = (BICollectionCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BICollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:YES];
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    if (self.selectedIndexPath == indexPath || ([objCustVehiclesList.modelName isEqualToString:self.str_ModelName] && _isCalledFromDetailVC) || (indexPath.row == self.indexPathToBeSearch.row && self.isCalledFromVehicleVC)) {
        [cell.imgSelectedImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vs_tick.png"]];
    }
    else {
        [cell.imgSelectedImage setImage:nil];
    }
    <----Label Values--->
    return Cell;
}
```

Now in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` check for already `selected` cell like this

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.isCalledFromVehicleVC || self.isCalledFromDetailVC)
    {
     self.isCalledFromVehicleVC = NO;
     self.isCalledFromDetailVC = NO;
    }
    if (self.selectedIndexPath == indexPath) {
        [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
    }
    else {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }        
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

**Note -**  Remove your `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` method there is no need of this now.

Comment: Welcome buddy, Happy Coding :)

Comment: if i m coming from another view by passign object and make it selected if object is avaliiable . in this case if i click on selected object it s not getting deselect

Comment: u there image not get change if any image s selected  when i m coming from another vc

Comment: Can you please edit the question with more detail and new code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117873/discussion-between-imran-and-nirav).

Comment: sure checking and let u know